# What motivated Einstein's postulate on the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, history

I know that there are several experiments (conducted after Einstein's formulation of Special Relativity) that confirm to some extend Einstein's postulate that nothing can travel faster than light. But my question is what motivated Einstein to make this assumption on the first place back in 1905.

A possible answer is due to the wave-like nature of light and the fact that a moving wave-source does not change the speed of the wave as long as the frequency is constant. But is this enough?

Apparently, *within* the theory, if this postulate is violated, several paradoxes appear. But my question is what motivated the postulate at the first place in order to build the theory based on the assumption that the speed of light is constant in all frames of reference.

I would really appreciate any light on that, as well as any resources or quotes from Einstein himself.

Comment: It comes from Maxwell's equations.  Maxwell predicted the existence of electromagnetic waves, and he predicted that they always would be obsevered to travel at a fixed speed, C, in any frame of reference. Many physicists wondered whether light was explained by Maxwell's electromagnetic waves, and they wondered about the consequences of that fixed speed. Einstein was the first one who was able to tie all of their various ideas into one coherent theory.

Comment: Check out the answers in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248499/

Comment: This belongs on the history of science stack, where [it has already been answered](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/622/the-motivation-for-relativity-theory). The only thing those answers don't seem to cover very well is that Einstein has a comment somewhere where he also mentions that he was impressed by Maxwell’s eqs (thus took Lorentz more seriously than he took himself), because you could calculate the current in a coil of wire when that wire was moving towards a magnet, and when the magnet was moving towards the wire. The equations described different physics, but the same current.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a history question that belongs on [hsm.se]. See [these guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930) for more details. (Though given the existing duplicate there, I'm unsure about the appropriateness of migration.)

Comment: Why is no one mentioning the Michelson-Morley experiment?

Comment: @SolomonSlow _"he predicted that they always would be obsevered to travel at a fixed speed"_ except he didn't. Michelson-Morley experiment is the answer to this question.

Comment: @gented The M-M experiment didn't predict anything. It was an _observation_ that seemed to support the idea that light and Maxwell's "electromagnetic radiation" might be one and the same phenomenon.

Comment: *Einstein's postulate that nothing can travel faster than light.*
Einstein never postulated that. It's a - far from immediate - consequence of Einstein's revision of Newton's dynamics. Second Einstein's postulate in his famous 1905 paper is *invariance of light speed*, i.e. it's the same in every inertial frame of reference. Apparently nobody commented on your (incorrect) statement.

Comment: @CRDrost *Einstein has a comment somewhere...* You may find it in the first page of Einstein's 1905 paper.

Comment: @SolomonSlow What does it even mean _"it didn't predict anything"_? Experiments never predict, they measure facts happening in nature and what Michelson and Morley measured was that the speed of light was the same in all reference frames. Nowhere in the Maxwell's equations is stated that the speed is independent of the reference frame.

Comment: @ElioFabri thank you! I had forgotten I had read the source paper! ([pdf](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf) for anyone else who is curious)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I apologise for the off-topic question.  I didn't know that there is a 'History of Science' stack page.

Answer (score 5):

There were several motivations for the postulate that the speed of light is constant in every frame of reference. First and foremost was Maxwell's work on Electromagnetism. Maxwell found that the vacuum solutions to his equations gives rise to waves which he recognized as light. He gave formula for the speed of light 
$$c=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}}$$
Since for all observers the value of $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ is same, the speed of light also must remain constant. Then there were also experiments like [Michelson Morley experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) and [Fizeau experiment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment) that had confirmed constancy of the speed of light (though they did not intend to).  There was enough scientific data for the postulate. In fact Henrik Lorentz had done the same two years before Einstein, that is why the relativistic transformations are named after him.